# jquery.fullPage.js how to enable scroll within a section for small monitor or smartphones

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Hello i have site and i added fullpage.js but for smartphones it doesn't work well so i want inside section for smarthpones will scroll normal and from section to section to change fullpage scroll !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the `overflowScroll:true` option?

[Example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html)

Comment: not working :/ it's work only for sections if i scroll down/up then it's link between start of sections but if section is big it don't go down to show other piece of section just scroll it and go to another section :/

Comment: my bad man . i am so sorry i found the problem it was something from your example ! example very helpful ! thank you very much !